# How to configure in int TestNG XML file to run only one test in the dataprovider set containing 3 tests

Tags: java, testng

How to configure in the  TestNG XML file to run only one test in the dataprovider set containing 3 tests

For a short regression i would like to run only one test from from the dataprovider set. Only TC1 for example.. Only when i need to run a complete regression i would like to run everything. Is there a way to configure this in the Testng XML?

```
@DataProvider(name = "testInternational")
public Object[][] testInternational() {
    return new Object[][]{
            {"TC1", "Afghanistan",Abo},
            {"TC2", "Albanië",Abo},
            {"TC3", "Zwitserland",Abo},    
    };
}
class Test {

@Test(dataProvider = "testInternational")//To retry a failed test a few times
public void testInternational(String testcase, String country, String type) {
    open(url);
    //do something
}
```

---

```
**Testng XML**
<test name="TestDataProvider">
    <parameter name="Browser" value="firefox /> 
    <classes>
        <class name="Test"/>
          <methods>
            <include name="testInternational" />
        </methods>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the code, you can use parameters or environment variable:

```
@DataProvider(name = "testInternational")
@Parameters({ "indices" })
public Object[][] testInternational(String indices) {
    // Instead of parameters, you can use sys env
    // String[] ids = System.getProperty("indices").split(":");
    String[] ids = indices.split(":"); 
    Object[][] values = new Object[][]{
            {"TC1", "Afghanistan",Abo},
            {"TC2", "Albanië",Abo},
            {"TC3", "Zwitserland",Abo},    
    };
    Object[][] result = new Object[ids.length][];
    for (int i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
       result[i] = values[Integer.parseInt(ids[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And

```
<test name="TestDataProvider">
    <parameter name="Browser" value="firefox /> 
    <classes>
        <class name="Test"/>
          <methods>
            <parameter name="indices" value="0:2" />
            <include name="testInternational" />
        </methods>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Otherwise, you can use the [`indices`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/DataProvider.html#indices--) property on `@DataProvider`.
And if you don't have access to the sources, you can modify the value with an [`IAnnotationTransformer2`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers).

```
public class MyAnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer2 {
  [...empty methods...]

  public void transform(IDataProviderAnnotation annotation, Method method) {
    if (method.getName().equals("testInternational")) {
      // Custom way to find indices (sys properties?)
      annotation.setIndices(Collections.asList(0, 2));
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can add the listener via `suite.xml` or `@Listeners` annotation.

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thanks. i will do that :)

Comment: Is the mvn command for running only one test in data provider?